# Rpush notification not working for FCM enabled app

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have developed android app that allows FCM notifications. I am using rpush gem to send these push notifications, but I believe rpush sends GCM instead of FCM notification. I am trying to learn if there is a tweak to send FCM notification via rpush without changing android app to switch to GCM.

Answer (score 0):

Try to check [the push notification service for Ruby by github](https://github.com/rpush/rpush).

It was stated that FCM (used to be GCM) is one of the supported services.

> Supported Services
>
> - Apple Push Notification Service
>
>   - Including Safari Push Notifications.
> - [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://github.com/rpush/rpush#firebase-cloud-messaging) (used to be Google Cloud Messaging)
> - Amazon Device Messaging
> - Windows Phone Push Notification Service

Based on Firebase Cloud Messaging

> FCM and GCM are – as of writing – compatible with each other. See also
>   [this comment](https://github.com/rpush/rpush/issues/284#issuecomment-228330206) for further references.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used rpush after reading that comment, but it does not seem to work. It stores the notification in rpush table but it's never sent. Notifications sent to my app using online push apps are working fine, but with rpush, they are not working